# Same origin Issue with iframe loaded from AWS S3

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, cross-domain, same-origin-policy

I just changed my blog from wordpress to django-zinnia. Zinnia uses a WYMeditor (https://github.com/wymeditor/wymeditor) iframe within django-admin for blog post text and content entry, and right now I can't access the iframe due to a same-origin issue. The error I'm seeing in browser console is:

```
Blocked a frame with origin "http://www.mydomain.com" from accessing a frame with origin "http://mybucket.s3.amazonaws.com". 
Protocols, domains, and ports must match.
WYMeditor.WymClassSafari.initIframe 
onload
```

Is there a parameter I can update in my CORS configurations for the bucket to allow the iframe to load cross-origin? I already have

```
 <AllowedOrigin>http://www.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
```

within my current CORS rules:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <CORSConfiguration xmlns="http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/2006-03-01/">
         <CORSRule>
             <AllowedOrigin>http://mydomain.herokuapp.com</AllowedOrigin>
             <AllowedOrigin>http://mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
             <AllowedOrigin>http://www.mydomain.com</AllowedOrigin>
             <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
             <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
             <AllowedHeader>Content-*</AllowedHeader>
             <AllowedHeader>Host</AllowedHeader>
             <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
        </CORSRule>
   </CORSConfiguration>
```

Comment: I'm fairly certain that CORS files do not affect iframes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The CORS headers do not affect the same-origin policy for iframes in Safari.

You can communicate between the frames using `postMessage` or you could attach a subdomain from `mydomain.com` to your S3 bucket and relax the same-origin policy by setting `document.domain` (this method only works to communicate between subdomains of the same domain, it doesn't work between different domains).

You can learn more about iframes communication from this answer on StackOverflow:

[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3076648/1027148)

Comment: thanks. very helpful. based on this document.domain with a subdomain is probably the best route. alternatively -- at least in my case since this only affects a template in admin, not any user-facing pages so I don't care about page performance/load time -- I could also just do a bad hack-around and insert the wymeditor js directly into the page from the template itself to solve my issue